# Set DNS manually on KDE

Tags: linux, networking, dns, kde, google-public-dns

The Network Manager on KDE gets DNS configuration from DHCP and sets it automatically, but I would like to use the [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/). If I overwrite  `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` it still resolves names with the old DNS (probably cached in memory) and, of course, even if it worked, it would be annoying having to do that every time I connect to a network.

I've noticed the Network Manager lets you specify a fixed DNS with the rest being taken from DHCP, but that's on a **per network** basis, and I would like to set it once for whichever network I connect to (if you're on the go with a laptop that becomes an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/2008/10/02/using-opendns-with-networkmanager-for-dhclient.html) entry explains static DNS setup which is done on per-interface basis.

Shortly: open or create the configuration file `/etc/dhclient-IFACE.conf` (IFACE would be eth0 for wired and wlan0 for wireless connection) and append an `prepend domain-name-servers NAME.SERVER.IP.ADDR;` line for each of Google nameservers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! if you leave out the `-IFACE`, it apparently works for _any_ interface.